# Convert SQL Server signed int to Binary(4)

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql, t-sql, ip-address

I messed up. I wanted to store IP addresses compactly in SQL Server and chose 'int' for the column type. 'int' are 32 bit signed integers while IPs really are [32 bit binarys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385552/datatype-for-storing-ip-address-in-sql-server).

My question is: How do I convert my existing signed int into Binary(4) in SQL Server and how should I properly parse the string-IP representation from .Net 'Request.UserHostAddress' to get Binary(4) (I'm using LinqtoSQL as my ORM).

Comment: Can you please examples of what the data looks like and what it should be, or what IP it represents?

Comment: Second GBN - if you can give us an example of what the data looks like as an INT (what's in your tables right now) and the corresponding IP (if you know it), we can make a better judgement about how to fix the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good article about [storing IP address data in SQL Server](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/2871/)