# SQL Server equivalent query for the given mysql query

Tags: sql-server, sqlbulkcopy, bcp

Table name : sample

Table structure :

```
ID         int
NAME       varchar(30)
IPADDRESS  varbinary(16)
```

mysql query :

```
load data concurrent local infile 'C:\test.txt' into table sample fields terminated by ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (ID,NAME,@var3) set IPADDRESS = inet_pton(@var3)
```

SQL Server equivalent query :

```
??
```

using bcp will be appreciated..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: if you know it requires bcp how about reading books onlne?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? SSIS is easy to use if you have it available.

Comment: @ Mitch  couldnt able to find the appropriate one for my need. My need is to do some operation on certain columns before bulk copy to table. could u pls help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article which you will find useful:

[How do I load text or csv file data into SQL Server?](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-load-text-or-csv-file-data-into-sql-server.html)

It was the second result from Google when searching for "bcp load file"

**EDIT:**

You might be able to do your import in two steps. Load the rows from the file in to a temp table then apply a function to convert the IP strings to the binary format.

Have a look at this question on SO: [Datatype for storing ip address in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385552/datatype-for-storing-ip-address-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.Did u note that i make use of the function inet_pton on the column3(IPADDRESS) before insertion thats wat i need. while doing bcp i need to perform some operation on certain columns..

Comment: @kumsmanju: No, I must admit I did not notice the use of `inet_pton` maybe you should emphasise that in your question. I will have a look at it again.

Comment: @kumsmanju: I've added some additional info to my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info but at a time millions of rows going to be dumped so dumping it to temp table and then transfering is quite cost.

Comment: Is it possible to use SSIS? In the import work flow you can create custom functions (using .NET languages) and perform the IP address conversion there.