# SQL Server join IP address to IP range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server, what's the simplest way to join a table of IPv4 addresses...

```
IPAddress
------------
10.70.80.34
10.70.81.60
10.70.81.205
```

To a table of IP ranges in CIDR notation...

```
IPRange          Description
---------------  -----------
10.70.80.0/24    Sydney
10.70.81.0/25    Melbourne
10.70.81.128/25  Perth
```

There will be fewer than 100 rows in the IP range table.

Comment: I assume your IPAddress and IPRange columns are `String`

Comment: Yes, both are nvarchar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote the following function which is OK for a small number of rows. For larger tables the IPs should be stored [in binary form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385552/datatype-for-storing-ip-address-in-sql-server).

```
CREATE FUNCTION IPAddressInRange
(
    @IPAddress NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @IPRange NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS BIT AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SlashPos INT = CHARINDEX('/', @IPRange);
    DECLARE @Network NVARCHAR(MAX) = SUBSTRING(@IPRange, 1, @SlashPos - 1);
    DECLARE @PrefixBits INT = CAST(SUBSTRING(@IPRange, @SlashPos + 1, 2) AS INT);

    DECLARE @IPAddressInt BIGINT =
        PARSENAME(@IPAddress, 4) * POWER(CAST(2 AS BIGINT), 24) +
        PARSENAME(@IPAddress, 3) * POWER(CAST(2 AS BIGINT), 16) +
        PARSENAME(@IPAddress, 2) * POWER(CAST(2 AS BIGINT), 8) +
        PARSENAME(@IPAddress, 1);

    DECLARE @NetworkInt BIGINT =
        PARSENAME(@Network, 4) * POWER(CAST(2 AS BIGINT), 24) +
        PARSENAME(@Network, 3) * POWER(CAST(2 AS BIGINT), 16) +
        PARSENAME(@Network, 2) * POWER(CAST(2 AS BIGINT), 8) +
        PARSENAME(@Network, 1);

    DECLARE @Mask BIGINT = POWER(CAST(2 AS BIGINT), 32) -
        POWER(CAST(2 AS BIGINT), 32 - @PrefixBits);

    RETURN CASE WHEN @IPAddressInt & @Mask = @NetworkInt THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
END
```

Example usage:

```
SELECT *
FROM IPAddressTable a
JOIN IPRangeTable r
ON dbo.IPAddressInRange(a.IPAddress, r.IPRange) = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`ParseName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) function may be useful for you in this scenario

```
DECLARE @ips table (
   ip_address varchar(15)
);

INSERT INTO @ips (ip_address)
  VALUES ('10.70.80.34')
       , ('10.70.81.60')
       , ('10.70.81.205');

SELECT ip_address
     , ParseName(ip_address, 4) As first_octet
     , ParseName(ip_address, 3) As second_octet
     , ParseName(ip_address, 2) As third_octet
     , ParseName(ip_address, 1) As fourth_octet
FROM   @ips
```

### Results

```
ip_address      first_octet   second_octet   third_octet  fourth_octet
--------------- ------------- -------------- ------------ -------------
10.70.80.34     10            70             80           34
10.70.81.60     10            70             81           60
10.70.81.205    10            70             81           205
```

Answer (score 1):

The same way you would do it in any other language - with a bunch of spelled out logic:

1. Convert the string to 4 integers
2. Determine the bit-mask (network mask)
3. Compare one number at a time from left to right after applying (bitwise `and`) the mask

The only thing special for SQL Server is that you want to avoid functions (with the exception of Inline Table Valued Functions). You also need to take into consideration that SQL Server is slow when it comes to String manipulation.

If the values are stored as strings I suggest to write a CLR function. In .NET code this is fairly simple to implement and the call overhead of a CLR scalar valued function is not that big. However, you will not be able to use an index on either table.

If the IPRange is a plain lookup table you are probably going to be fine. However, if you are going to write queries that return all IP addresses that fall into a specific range, this might become a problem. In that case I suggest to store the four integers of the IP addresses as well as the for integers of the mask in separate fields. That way indexing is possible and the join logic turns into a fairly simple expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PostgreSQL there is a simpler method do same:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IPInRange(VARCHAR(16), VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
    SELECT CAST($1 AS inet) << CAST($2 AS inet);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```