# Binary IP Search in Classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have a table with CIDR Blocks and I've converted them to StartIP and EndIP in Binary(4). I want to search that table with a user-supplied IP (IPV4) and return any records where the IP falls in between the StartIP and EndIP.

For background, see: [Convert IP to 32-bit Binary in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429578/convert-ip-to-32-bit-binary-in-tsql)

The following works in TSQL (returns 1 record):

```
declare @Binary varbinary(25)
select @Binary = MyDB.dbo.fnBinaryIPv4Start('204.228.241.25')

select field1, field2 from MyDB.dbo.MyTable WHERE (@Binary >= IPStartBinary AND @Binary <= IPEndBinary)
```

However this doesn't return any records in Classic ASP:

```
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
            cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
            cmd.ActiveConnection =objConn

            strSQL2 = "SELECT MyDB.dbo.fnBinaryIPV4Start(?)"

            'IP Parameter
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@IP",adVarChar,adParamInput,15,strIP)
            cmd("@IP") = strIP

            cmd.CommandText = strSQL2
            strBinary = cmd.Parameters(0)

            Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
            cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
            cmd.ActiveConnection = objConn
            cmd.CommandTimeOut = 1200    

            strSQL = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM MyDB.dbo.MyTable WHERE (? >= IPStartBinary AND ? <= IPEndBinary) "
            cmd.Parameters.Append (cmd.CreateParameter("IP", adVarBinary, adParamInput, 50, strBinary))
            cmd.Parameters.Append (cmd.CreateParameter("IP", adVarBinary, adParamInput, 50, strBinary))
        End If

cmd.CommandText = strSQL
set objRS = cmd.Execute
if not objRS.EOF then
arrMyResults = objRS.GetRows()
strMyRewultsUbound = UBound(arrMyResults,2)
end if

objRS.close
set objRS = nothing
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: i do not understand the first part of your asp code? you never execute the strSQL2? so you never get the ip as binary? try to Response.write the strBinary variable

Comment: If you convert your comment to an answer I'll accept it as my answer...

Comment: I'd recommend converting the SQL into a stored procedure that accepts a single argument (the IP as a string) and returns a record set. You can then simplify your ASP code to a single command execution (`adCmdStoredProc`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i do not understand the first part of your asp code? you never execute the strSQL2? so you never get the ip as binary? try to Response.write the strBinary variable