# SQL Server: Inserting from various sources

Tags: sql, sql-server

The simple version

What is the correct syntax of this?

```
INSERT INTO foo(IP, referer)
VALUES(SELECT bin FROM dbo.bar("foobar"),"www.foobar.com/test/")
```

I am getting syntax errors near 'SELECT' and ')'

The long version: I want to insert using a Function and a string (this is simplified, in reality there will be a few other values including datetime, ints, etc to insert along with the function result).

I have a function, itvfBinaryIPv4, which was set up to convert IPs to a binary(4) datatype to allow for easy indexing, I used this as a reference: [Datatype for storing ip address in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385552/datatype-for-storing-ip-address-in-sql-server).

So this is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
INSERT INTO foo (IP, referer)
VALUES(SELECT bin FROM dbo.itvfBinaryIPv4("192.65.68.201"), "www.foobar.com/test/")
```

However, I get syntax errors near 'SELECT' and ')'. What is the correct syntax to insert with function results and direct data?

Comment: itvfBinaryIPv4 is scaller function or table valued function ??

Comment: Table-valued function. Like I said, I ran the create statement from that referenced SO article, and it was placed under Table-valued Functions automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this -

```
INSERT INTO foo (IP, referer)
   SELECT bin, 'www.foobar.com/test/' 
   FROM dbo.itvfBinaryIPv4('192.65.68.201')
```

here assume `dbo.itvfBinaryIPv4("192.65.68.201")` is table valued function.

Comment: That worked, except for a few minor changes: INSERT INTO foo (referer, IP) SELECT 'www.foobar.com/test/', bin FROM dbo.itvfBinaryIPv4('192.65.68.201'). [Switched the column names in the selector set and changed double quotes to single quotes in the function's parameters]

Comment: Also wanted to add how to SELECT using the scalar-valued binary-to-IP function: SELECT referer, dbo.fnDisplayIPv4(IP) FROM foobar

Comment: Yes that's right. you can use this query in insert statement - `SELECT referer, dbo.fnDisplayIPv4(IP) FROM foobar`

Answer (score 1):

The `INSERT` command comes in two flavors:

**(1)** either you have all your values available, as literals or SQL Server variables - in that case, you can use the `INSERT .. VALUES()` approach:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
VALUES(Value1, Value2, @Variable3, @Variable4, ...., ValueN)
```

Note: I would recommend to **always** explicitly specify the list of column to insert data into - that way, you won't have any nasty surprises if suddenly your table has an extra column, or if your tables has an `IDENTITY` or computed column. Yes - it's a tiny bit more work - **once** - but then you have your `INSERT` statement as solid as it can be and you won't have to constantly fiddle around with it if your table changes.

**(2)** if you **don't** have all your values as literals and/or variables, but instead you want to rely on another table, multiple tables, or views, to provide the values, then you can use the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` approach:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
   SELECT
       SourceColumn1, SourceColumn2, @Variable3, @Variable4, ...., SourceColumnN
   FROM
       dbo.YourProvidingTableOrView
```

Here, you must define exactly as many items in the `SELECT` as your `INSERT` expects - and those can be columns from the table(s) (or view(s)), or those can be literals or variables. Again: explicitly provide the list of columns to insert into - see above.

You can use **one or the other** - but you **cannot** mix the two - you cannot use `VALUES(...)` and then have a `SELECT` query in the middle of your list of values - pick one of the two - stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't checked it, but the correct syntax would be:

```
INSERT INTO foo (IP, referer)
SELECT bin,  "www.foobar.com/test/" FROM dbo.itvfBinaryIPv4("192.65.68.201")
```