# Running SQL function as PDO prepared statement and returning values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to store IP addres of a user in the database and based on this [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385552/datatype-for-storing-ip-address-in-sql-server) I learnt that IP addresses should be stored in BINARY format.

Running the function as a prepared statement - I can bind the @ip as $text parameter

```
$stmt = $this->dbconnect->prepare ('CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnBinaryIPv4(@:ip AS VARCHAR(15)) RETURNS BINARY(4)
        AS
        BEGIN
        DECLARE @bin AS BINARY(4)
        SELECT @bin = CAST( CAST( PARSENAME( @ip, 4 ) AS INTEGER) AS BINARY(1))
        + CAST( CAST( PARSENAME( @ip, 3 ) AS INTEGER) AS BINARY(1))
        + CAST( CAST( PARSENAME( @ip, 2 ) AS INTEGER) AS BINARY(1))
        + CAST( CAST( PARSENAME( @ip, 1 ) AS INTEGER) AS BINARY(1))
        RETURN @bin
 END;');


    $stmt->execute(array(':ip'=>$text));
```

How can I use the returned value (@bin)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code you are not executing the stored function, but you are creating it. If you want to execute a previously created stored function, simply select it's return value

e.g.:

```
$stmt = $this->dbconnect->prepare ('SELECT dbo.fnBinaryIPv4(:ip) as bin');
$stmt->execute(array(':ip'=>$text));
```