# Calling SQL Server functions from an Access form

Tags: sql-server, function, ms-access

I'm looking for a correct way to use SQL Server functions in an Access front-end. It's fairly simple to use it one way - just need to call function, use brackets and voila - ready. But I've stuck on the other case. Whtt if there are two separate functions: one to "code" and the second one to "decode" data? Background of the problem can be found here: [Datatype for storing ip address in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385552/datatype-for-storing-ip-address-in-sql-server). I would like to use this example in my access app, but how to do two separate, one way operations in MS Access form? Of course if there is need to create additional view or any additional layer to achieve this beside creating a form, I'm not very stubborn and just a little lazy - I'll be happy to do that.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do or what the issue is here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe can indeed be accomplished with an Access form bound to an ODBC linked table. What you need to do is create two controls on the form

1. a hidden control bound to the field in the linked table, and
2. a visible unbound control that the user can interact with.

For example, say you have an ODBC linked table named [dbo_temperatures] pointing to a SQL Server table that stores temperature values in Celsius:

```sql
-- (code to create the table in SQL Server Management Studio)
CREATE TABLE dbo.temperatures (
    id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
    observed DATETIME, 
    tempC INT)
```

You also have two scalar functions in SQL Server to convert values from Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice-versa

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnCtoF(@tempC AS INT) RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @t AS FLOAT;
    SET @t = CONVERT(FLOAT, @tempC);
    RETURN CONVERT(INT, (@t * 9 / 5) + 32);
END
```

and

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnFtoC(@tempF AS INT) RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @t AS FLOAT;
    SET @t = CONVERT(FLOAT, @tempF);
    RETURN CONVERT(INT, (@t - 32) * 5 / 9);
END
```

On your form (bound to the linked table [dbo_temperatures]) you create

1. a hidden text box named "txtTempC" that is bound to the [tempC] field, and
2. a visible unbound text box named "txtTempF".

The form has two private VBA functions to call the SQL Server functions

```vbs
Private Function getFahrenheit(t As Variant) As Variant
    If IsNull(t) Then
        getFahrenheit = Null
    Else
        Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef, rst As DAO.Recordset
        Set cdb = CurrentDb
        Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("")
        qdf.Connect = cdb.TableDefs("dbo_temperatures").Connect
        qdf.SQL = "SELECT dbo.fnCtoF(" & t & ") AS x"
        qdf.ReturnsRecords = True
        Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
        getFahrenheit = rst!x
        rst.Close
        Set rst = Nothing
        Set qdf = Nothing
        Set cdb = Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

and

```vbs
Private Function getCelsius(t As Variant) As Variant
    If IsNull(t) Then
        getCelsius = Null
    Else
        Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef, rst As DAO.Recordset
        Set cdb = CurrentDb
        Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("")
        qdf.Connect = cdb.TableDefs("dbo_temperatures").Connect
        qdf.SQL = "SELECT dbo.fnFtoC(" & t & ") AS x"
        qdf.ReturnsRecords = True
        Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
        getCelsius = rst!x
        rst.Close
        Set rst = Nothing
        Set qdf = Nothing
        Set cdb = Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Then you can use the On Current event of the Form to populate the Fahrenheit text box

```vbs
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.txtTempF.Value = getFahrenheit(Me.txtTempC.Value)
End Sub
```

and the After Update event of the Fahrenheit text box to update the Celsius text box.

```vbs
Private Sub txtTempF_AfterUpdate()
    Me.txtTempC.Value = getCelsius(Me.txtTempF.Value)
End Sub
```

Because the Celsius text box is bound to the [tempC] field, the change will be written back to the table when the record is saved.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to decode some data in a query with your function, display the decoded data in the form, edit it there and then, while saving the data, encode it back with another function.

This is not possible in a data bound form in Access. Access always tries to write the data entered in a form-field directly to the corresponding table- or query-field. It is not possible to do any data processing (the call to the encoding function) in between.

One way to achieve this is with an unbound form. 
You create a form that is not bound to any recordsource, then you read the data from your query into a recordset and write the recordset data to the controls in the form. To save the data read the contents of the controls, create an sql update statement that call your encoding function and saves the data to the table.