# MS Access using forms in a pass-through query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a form named *FietsAantDagen*, a query named *QueryFietsAantDagen* and a textbox named *Txtinput*. I am trying to use a pass-through query to SQL Server and use a text form's input as a input in my query.

Query:

```
SELECT
   Fiets_id,
   Fiets_Type,
   SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum, Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum)) AS AantalDagen 
FROM
   Fiets 
   INNER JOIN
      HuurovereenkomstFiets 
      ON HuurovereenkomstFiets_Fiets_id = Fiets_id 
   INNER JOIN
      Huurovereenkomst 
      ON Huurovereenkomst_id = HuurovereenkomstFiets_Huurovereenkomst_id 
WHERE
   YEAR(Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum) = [Forms]![FietsAantDagen]![Txtinput] 
   AND YEAR(Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum) = [Forms]![FietsAantDagen]![Txtinput] 
GROUP BY
   Fiets_id,
   Fiets_Type
```

While running this query as a pass-through query I get the following error:

> ODBC: Runtime error [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'/ (#156)

Is the problem that I am using an Access text form value in a pass-through query, if so what can I do to solve it?

I read in another Overflow question you needed to add (), which I did and now I get the error:

> JOIN-expression is not supported.

I'm going crazy...

Comment: Look at the syntax for a select query. GROUP BY comes AFTER the WHERE clause.

Comment: Here is the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql

Comment: Oops, made a mistake copying it from the other comment. Now it gives the same error but with: Incorrect syntax near '!'. (#102)

Comment: Use SSMS to debug your query before passing it through.

Comment: Well it's hard when you are trying to add a MS Access form into a SQL Server query.....

Comment: I would not build a pass through like this myself. It is a pain to deal with. If this was my project I would create a procedure in sql server and execute that procedure from Access. Keeps everything separated which means if you ever decide that Access is no longer the best front end you just change the front end and all your data retrieval is still intact.

Comment: Well I tried, I have this query in a function and try this: SELECT * FROM fnFietsAantDagenPerJaar([Forms]![FietsAantDagen]![Txtinput]). It still gives me the input error near '!'...

Comment: What is fnFietsAantDagenPerJaar? Is that a table valued function in sql server or is that a scalar function?

Comment: @SeanLange I updated my post with the information, it is a table valued function

Comment: I haven't done this type of thing in Access in a LONG time. But you should parameterize your call.

Comment: Pretty sure the answer you seek can be found here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681026/calling-sql-server-functions-from-an-access-form

Comment: Edited my question, I am really stuck now....

Comment: Did you see the link I posted? To be honest I would suggest you take a step back and breathe. At this point you are just throwing code at the problem hoping something will work.

Comment: You should use VBA to achieve this, not just a query. Execute the query (preferably using ADO), and pass the form values as parameters. Since you're using a passthrough query, they need to be validly marked as parameters in T-SQL (they're currently valid parameters in JET/Ace SQL only), I'd personally use questionmarks (of course, you can use string concatenation too, as shown in the link, but I highly recommend you don't)

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t have direct use of SQL server, then likely best to create two pass though queries.

Query #1 – this is your raw SQL as you have
Eg:

```
SELECT
    Fiets_id,
    Fiets_Type,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum,
    Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum)) AS AantalDagen 
FROM
   Fiets 
INNER JOIN
  HuurovereenkomstFiets 
  ON HuurovereenkomstFiets_Fiets_id = Fiets_id 
INNER JOIN
  Huurovereenkomst 
  ON Huurovereenkomst_id = HuurovereenkomstFiets_Huurovereenkomst_id 
WHERE
  YEAR(Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum) = [StartYear]
  AND YEAR(Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum) = [EndYear]
GROUP BY
  Fiets_id,
   Fiets_Type
```

Query #2 – this is an application wide query you make that you can re-use over and over for any raw t-SQL (SQL server pass though). You then in code go like this:

```
Dim rst     As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL  As String

strSQL = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyQ1").SQL
srtSQL = Replace(strSQL, "[YearStart]", [Forms]![FietsAantDagen]![Txtinput])
strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "[YearEnd]", [Forms]![FietsAantDagen]![Txtinput])
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPassR")
   .SQL = strSQL
  .ReturnsRecords = True
  Set rst = .OpenRecordset
End With
```

However, if you have the ability to use SQL server, and create a proc, then I would suggest you create store procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectDates
@StartYear int,
@EndYear int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
 SELECT
   Fiets_id,
   Fiets_Type,
   SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum, Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum)) AS AantalDagen 
FROM
Fiets 
   INNER JOIN
    HuurovereenkomstFiets 
  ON HuurovereenkomstFiets_Fiets_id = Fiets_id 
INNER JOIN
   Huurovereenkomst 
   ON Huurovereenkomst_id = HuurovereenkomstFiets_Huurovereenkomst_id 
WHERE
YEAR(Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum) = @StartYear
AND YEAR(Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum) = @EndYear
GROUP BY
   Fiets_id,
   Fiets_Type

END
```

Then in access, you use this:

```
Dim rst     As DAO.Recordset

With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPassR")
   .SQL = "exec SelectDates " & [Forms]![FietsAantDagen]![Txtinput] & "," & _
          [Forms]![FietsAantDagen]![Txtinput]
  .ReturnsRecords = True
  Set rst = .OpenRecordset
End With
```

So by passing parameters you reduce most of issues in regards to SQL injection.
Of course if you can’t create store procs, or don’t have permissions, then you have to adopt the first idea above. You can also of course in the first suggestion insert the raw SQL into the code editor, but I find using up an extra query to “just” hold the raw SQL, and then modifying the SQL into the 2nd pass-through query eliminates the need for messy SQL in the VBA code editor.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a Pass-Through query, its SQL text gets sent to the DB server as-is, nothing is evaluated. So including `[Forms]![FietsAantDagen]![Txtinput]` in a Pass-Through query will never work.

You're on the right track with

```
SELECT * FROM fnFietsAantDagenPerJaar([Forms]![FietsAantDagen]![Txtinput])‌​
```

but you need to supply the parameter yourself, because (see above).

So you need to build the Pass-Through SQL, e.g. with this VBA procedure:

```vb
Private Sub txtInput_AfterUpdate()

    Dim QD As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim lYear As Long

    ' Make sure we pass a number to the SQL Server function
    lYear = Val(Me!txtInput)
    If lYear > 0 Then
        Set QD = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("QueryFietsAantDagen")
        QD.SQL = "SELECT * FROM fnFietsAantDagenPerJaar(" & lYear & ")"
        Set QD = Nothing

        ' After changing the query SQL, requery the form
        ' This assumes that your form is bound to Pass-Through query QueryFietsAantDagen
        Me.Requery
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass-through queries run exclusively on the connected, external database engine, here being SQL Server, and does not see anything in MS Access, only everything in that external environment.

Consider adjusting pass-through query to avoid any MS Access evaluations and add *year* groupings to aggregate query. Then query this resultset in a local Access query filtering for needed *year* conditions using form values. Below adds table aliases for clarity (adjust if not correct).

**Pass-Through** *(no `WHERE` clause, but extended `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`)*

```
SELECT
   f.Fiets_id,
   f.Fiets_Type,
   YEAR(h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum) As BeginYear,
   YEAR(h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum) As EndYear,
   SUM(DATEDIFF('d', h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum, 
                     h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum)) AS AantalDagen 
FROM
    HuurovereenkomstFiets_LinkTable hf
    INNER JOIN
      Fiets_LinkTable f
      ON hf.HuurovereenkomstFiets_Fiets_id = f.Fiets_id 
    INNER JOIN
      Huurovereenkomst_LinkTable h
      ON h.Huurovereenkomst_id = hf.HuurovereenkomstFiets_Huurovereenkomst_id 
GROUP BY
   f.Fiets_id,
   f.Fiets_Type,
   YEAR(h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum),
   YEAR(h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum)
```

**Local Query**

```
SELECT
   t.Fiets_id,
   t.Fiets_Type,
   t.AantalDagen 
FROM
   myPassThroughQuery t
WHERE t.BeginYear = [Forms]![FietsAantDagen]![Txtinput]
  AND t.EndYear = [Forms]![FietsAantDagen]![Txtinput]
```

---

Alternatively, consider using linked tables from SQL Server (with same ODBC connection as pass-through) where Access can treat them as local tables. Hence, you can run your query using form date values. Do note you will have to convert syntax to adhere to Access' SQL dialect like `DATEDIFF` and `JOIN` parentheses. Performance may differ due to changed engines but test.

**Linked Tables Local Query**

```
SELECT
   f.Fiets_id,
   f.Fiets_Type,
   SUM(DATEDIFF('d', h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum, 
                     h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum)) AS AantalDagen 
FROM
   (HuurovereenkomstFiets_LinkTable hf
    INNER JOIN
      Fiets_LinkTable f
      ON hf.HuurovereenkomstFiets_Fiets_id = f.Fiets_id) 
    INNER JOIN
      Huurovereenkomst_LinkTable h
      ON h.Huurovereenkomst_id = hf.HuurovereenkomstFiets_Huurovereenkomst_id 
WHERE YEAR(h.Huurovereenkomst_Begin_datum) = [Forms]![FietsAantDagen]![Txtinput] 
  AND YEAR(h.Huurovereenkomst_Eind_datum) = [Forms]![FietsAantDagen]![Txtinput] 
GROUP BY
   f.Fiets_id,
   f.Fiets_Type
```

To create linked tables automatically, use [DoCmd.TransferDatabase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-transferdatabase-method-access). Otherwise, use the [External Data / ODBC Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZcWP.png) icon on ribbon and walk through setup wizard.

```vb
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", _
    "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=<ServerAddress>;Database=<DBname>;Trusted_Connection=Yes;", _
    acTable, "HuurovereenkomstFiets", "HuurovereenkomstFiets_LinkedTable"
```