# how to use LIKE with column name (2)

Tags: mysql, ms-access, xampp, odbc

This is in continutation of the question asked here:
[how to use LIKE with column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398720/how-to-use-like-with-column-name)

since i do not have enough reputation i am unable to add it to the question there itself.  My question is:

1. I am using Microsoft Access with ODBC connectivity to MySql
2. There is a linked table to it
3. i wan to query the table using a text box on a Form
4. i am unable to do so with the error 'ODBC--call failed'

this is the sql statement of my query:

```
SELECT 
    'Completed',  
    'Entity Name',  
    'Assignment',  
    'Financial Year',  
    'Service Area',  
    'Partner/Director',  
    'Intern 1',  
    'Intern 2',  
    Payment_recddate,
    Invoice_Amount',  
    'MinOfStart Date',  
    'MinOfDue Date',  
    PAN,
    AssignmentID,  
    Priority1CompletedRatio
FROM 
    qry_Assignments_WIP_sub
WHERE 
    [Entity Name] Like 
        CONCAT([Forms]![frm_Assignments_WIP]![txtEntitynameFilter],'%')
```

I am doing something wrong in it and am at wits end trying to get this right
[image]

In reply to cha
    WHERE qry_Assignments_WIP_sub.`Entity Name` Like "CONCAT('" & [Forms]!    [frm_Assignments_WIP]![txtEntitynameFilter] & "','%')"')

still getting the error[image]

Comment: Reboot your computer and then check your connection to the database.  I think this is more of a question for Server Fault or Superuser... it's not really programming related.

Comment: trying since last 3 days, error still persists!  It has something to do with syntax of the WHERE and LIKE.  If i remove the WHERE line, i do get a result.  There is blank result when i ask the query to take the value from the Form field.

Comment: omg I can read the code now. Isn't it better when it's cleaned up?  It's still the same code.  Anyhow I'm not sure if those `'` were there in your code or you added them on the site, but they shouldn't be there.  Also what are you trying to accomplish with `CONCAT([Forms]![frm_Assignments_WIP]![txtEntitynameFilter],'%')`?\

Comment: Also are you using**[tag:mysql] or [tag:ms-access]**?  There are a lot of differences, including deciding whether you're using the correct wildcard.  **Please delete any irrelevant tags.**

Comment: as i mentioned i am using access on mysql database and the query is selected to be a passthrough.  don't get it why u mentioning 'Please delete any irrelevant tags'

Comment: You can't use `Forms!...` in a Pass-Through query. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120992/ms-access-using-forms-in-a-pass-through-query

Comment: @andre still now working! :(

Comment: @Andre , i am getting an error when the cursor comes to the part Set rst = .OpenRecordset

Comment: *i am getting an error* - you'll have to be more specific than that. Add the code you are using to your question, and state the full error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the last line. Looks like you are trying to use a value from the form and not inserting the actual value. What you need to do is this:

```
"CONCAT('" & [Forms]![frm_Assignments_WIP]![txtEntitynameFilter] & "','%')"
```

Comment: um, shouldn't that also be a `*` instead of a `%`?  (If the calls are being made through Access.)

Comment: I do not think so. `CONCAT` is not Access function

Comment: @ ashleedawg, @cha, since its a query on mysql, it will be %, concat is mysql function .  see point 2 of this link https://www.convert-in.com/msaccess-queries-to-mysql.htm

Comment: @cha is it possible to do so in a passthrough query?  i am using a passthrough query

Comment: Yes it is possible. Show us your VBA code and we will help you out