# How to call SQL-Server user-defined function using access vba

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

It is possible to call window sql database user-defined function using access vba code?

I found a function call db.testFunction(id) in the sql database; I use SQLNCL11.1 as the provider and I use ADODB for the connection.

How do I use this function in access vba code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling SQL Server functions from an Access form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681026/calling-sql-server-functions-from-an-access-form)

Comment: You can't use that in vba-code (but you can create an sql-command via vba containing the function), it can only be used by (and on) the sql-server via an sql-command. Any reason using deprecated SQLNCL and not [Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this application has working linked tables?

Then just create a pass-though query. Type in your functon with a select statement in front. Run the pt query. It should return your value.
So, in the query builder, creaate that PT query.
For the source of the PT query you can type in any valid t-sql, but in this case, it makes sense to type in a test of the function.

Say this:

```
SELECT dbo.textFunction(12)
```

If that works (and MAKE SURE you get it working - you not written one line of code). Once you have that PT query working?

Then you can use this VBA code:

```
Sub Test33434()

   Dim lngID           As Long
   Dim lngReturnValue  As Long
   
   lngID = 1234
   
   With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPass")
      .SQL = "select dbo.testFunction(" & lngID & ")"
      lngReturnValue = .OpenRecordset()(0)
   End With

End Sub
```

So, in above we have the value we pass, and the return value.
And note how we don't have to mess with any connection object in code - so using a saved PT query is nice, since you don't have connection strings in code.