# SQL query to show values from one table that are in between column values in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sccm

So I have two tables. One table (tbl1) contains information for subnets by building, the column names are **ip_address, location, server, building, starting IP, ending IP, and subnet mask**.

I have another table (tbl2) with columns named **top console user, computer name, IP address, computer model, computer operating system, and computer serial number**

I would like to create a report that lists the IP addresses from tbl2 that fall in between the starting IP and ending IP in tbl1. So for example if a computer from tbl2 has an ip address 172.16.1.4 and tbl1 has a building whose starting ip is 172.16.1.1 and ending ip is 172.16.1.254 I would like to be able to see that in my report.

There are no similar columns in either table so using a JOIN statement has not really worked for me. I also use parameters (if that matters) in my report. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

I know this is a lot but it gets me halfway there. I created a function that converts values but not sure how to call. Any more pointers??

```
SELECT * FROM Subnets_And_Locations,
 (SELECT Computer_System_DATA.UserName00 AS Top_Console_User, 
Computer_System_DATA.Name00 + '.' + Computer_System_DATA.Domain00 AS Computer_Name,
System_IP_Address_ARR.IP_Addresses0 AS IP_Address, 
Computer_System_DATA.Model00 AS Model, 
Operating_System_DATA.Caption00 AS Operating_System,
PC_BIOS_DATA.SerialNumber00 AS Serial_Number 
FROM     Computer_System_DATA 
INNER JOIN Operating_System_DATA ON Computer_System_DATA.MachineID = Operating_System_DATA.MachineID
INNER JOIN System_IP_Address_ARR ON Computer_System_DATA.MachineID = System_IP_Address_ARR.ItemKey
INNER JOIN PC_BIOS_DATA ON Computer_System_DATA.MachineID = PC_BIOS_DATA.MachineID) AS Scope
WHERE Scope.IP_Address >= Subnets_And_Locations.Starting_IP AND Scope.IP_Address <= Subnets_And_Locations.Ending_IP
;
```

Comment: I am not sure there is a way to query a range of numbers like that (not 100% sure though). My suggestion would be to change how the IP addresses are stored in the table to make such a query possible. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385552/datatype-for-storing-ip-address-in-sql-server) which may be able to assist in how the data is stored.

Comment: the range is decided only by the last 2 octets or last 3 ?

Comment: the range is decided by the last 2 octets.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first casting the ip parts to their corresponding full format and remove the dots . for example convert 172.16.1.254 to 172016001254 and then the ranges can be easily compared by just doing a `>=` and `<=` . you can even store these values beforehand to speed this process up. By the way joins are totally fine. just use the conditions in the on clause.

Comment: Since IPv4 has 4 numbers up to 255 (or hex FF), it might be better to convert them directly into int so that there's no gaps in the number series, which might be useful later -- so 172.16.1.254 is 2886730238, and you can handle everything just like numbers.

Comment: so I would need to create a function?

Comment: It would too much to do I guess. I suggest adding a column to the existing table.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a.IP_address,
a.location,
a.server,
a.building,
b.*

from table_1 a
join table_2 b on b.ip_address >= a.[starting ip] 
 and b.ip_address <= a.[ending ip]
```

This should work for you or you can try it this way

```
Select a.IP_address,
a.location,
a.server,
a.building,
b.*

from table_2 b
join table_1 a on b.ip_address >= a.[starting ip] 
 and b.ip_address <= a.[ending ip]
```

I am not sure what you want in the report. There may be one more filkter you need to add, but hard to tell without me trying it out on my end.