# SQL to find IP Address in Subnet

Tags: sql-server

We recently started using the MaxMind Geolite Database as a lookup for cities based on IP.  There are plenty of instructions for getting the data into SQL Server (which I've done).  Now I need to figure out how to search for a given IP within a subnet.

DB Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE GeoIP (   
    network varchar(20) not null,
    geoname_id varchar(20) not null,
    registered_country_geoname_id varchar(20) not null,
    represented_country_geoname_id varchar(20) not null,
    is_anonymous_proxy int,
    is_satellite_provider int,
    postal_code varchar(20),
    latitude Decimal(9,6),
    longitude Decimal(9,6),
    accuracy_radius int
);
```

The 'network' column has row data with IP/Subnet (ex: 1.0.32.0/19, 1.0.64.0/20, 1.0.80.0/22)

Given a single IP address, I'm trying to write a SELECT statement that will return the geoname_id.

```
Ex: SELECT geoname_id FROM GeoIP where @user_ip in {some expression}
```

I'd like to do this without having to explode out the network column into a 'low_ip' and 'high_ip' BIGINT columns.  But, if that is the only way to do it, I could also use some help on how to write a global UPDATE statement to add the those columns from the existing data.

Need this for SQL SERVER 2008 so can't use any of the cool Postgres, etc.  functionality.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your network column you can already see the number of bits in the netmask and with the help of a little bitwise arithmetic, easily detect if a user ip falls within that network. Therefore I would suggest you split that column into its (binary) network ip and its cidr number.

Let me explain. If we take the first example you provided (10.0.32.0/19) we can see that it's netmask (the "/19" bit) is represented in binary as 19 ones with all the other bits set to zero:

```
11111111 11111111 11100000 00000000
```

Let's take a sample user ip of 1.0.32.56:

```
00000001 00000000 00100000 00111000
```

You can see that if you take the bitwise AND of that /19 netmask along with the user ip, you'll end up with:

```
00000001 00000000 00100000 00000000
```

...which converts to dotted quads as 1.0.32.0. Look familiar?

Anyway, here's the approach I'd take for your problem. First of all we need to use a udf to convert the ip address to binary. I'm shamelessly stealing the one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1385701/5393164):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnBinaryIPv4(@ip AS VARCHAR(15)) RETURNS BINARY(4)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @bin AS BINARY(4)

    SELECT @bin = CAST( CAST( PARSENAME( @ip, 4 ) AS INTEGER) AS BINARY(1))
            + CAST( CAST( PARSENAME( @ip, 3 ) AS INTEGER) AS BINARY(1))
            + CAST( CAST( PARSENAME( @ip, 2 ) AS INTEGER) AS BINARY(1))
            + CAST( CAST( PARSENAME( @ip, 1 ) AS INTEGER) AS BINARY(1))

    RETURN @bin
END
GO
```

I also find it helpful to have all of the netmasks in a small lookup table:

```
CREATE TABLE netmask (
    bits TINYINT PRIMARY KEY,
    binary_mask BINARY(4) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO netmask (bits, binary_mask) VALUES
    ( 0, 0x00000000), ( 1, 0x80000000), ( 2, 0xc0000000), ( 3, 0xe0000000),
    ( 4, 0xf0000000), ( 5, 0xf8000000), ( 6, 0xfc000000), ( 7, 0xfe000000),
    ( 8, 0xff000000), ( 9, 0xff800000), (10, 0xffc00000), (11, 0xffe00000),
    (12, 0xfff00000), (13, 0xfff80000), (14, 0xfffc0000), (15, 0xfffe0000),
    (16, 0xffff0000), (17, 0xffff8000), (18, 0xffffc000), (19, 0xffffe000),
    (20, 0xfffff000), (21, 0xfffff800), (22, 0xfffffc00), (23, 0xfffffe00),
    (24, 0xffffff00), (25, 0xffffff80), (26, 0xffffffc0), (27, 0xffffffe0),
    (28, 0xfffffff0), (29, 0xfffffff8), (30, 0xfffffffc), (31, 0xfffffffe),
    (32, 0xffffffff)
```

Next we create our two new columns and populate them:

```
ALTER TABLE GeoIP
ADD binary_network BINARY(4), network_bits TINYINT
GO

UPDATE GeoIP
SET binary_network = dbo.fnBinaryIPv4(SUBSTRING(network, 0, PATINDEX('%/%', network))),
    network_bits = CAST(SUBSTRING(network, PATINDEX('%/%', network) + 1, 3) AS TINYINT)
```

So now we can rewrite your query as:

```
DECLARE @binary_user_ip BIGINT
SELECT @binary_user_ip = dbo.fnBinaryIPv4(@user_ip)

SELECT geoname_id
FROM GeoIP g
    JOIN netmask n ON g.network_bits = n.bits
WHERE @binary_user_ip & n.binary_mask = g.binary_network
```

Note - this will only work with IPv4. If you want to detect IPv6 subnets, the general approach is the same but the string conversion and arithmetic will be more... complicated.

Comment: this works great.  can you explain what this line does?  (where @binary_user_ip & n.binary_mask = g.binary_network).

Comment: Also, if i'm using the binary_network as my primary search column, should I index that column?

Comment: That line is the bitwise AND. Same thing as that binary example I showed you before. And yeah, if binary_network is your primary search column you should almost certainly index it.

Comment: @duckbenny
Your answer works well, however, there is a mistake in the [netmask] table insert clause.
The binary_mask value for bits [23] ought to be [0xfffffe00]. Apologies to the mods, I've just joined and my reputation is too low to comment.