# MSSQL IP addresses Update to Binary (32)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, ip-address

I have problem to convert my IP addresses (in table as varchar) to binary (32) format

I have table

```
NETWORKS
Network_IP    Network_IP_in_binary   subnet_of_IP   subnet_of_IP_in_binary
24.55.186.203     NULL                    23           NULL
24.55.185.203     NULL                    45           NULL
24.55.184.203     NULL                    74           NULL
24.55.181.203     NULL                    45           NULL
24.55.183.203     NULL                    78           NULL
...                ...                    ...           ...
```

select / function / update

```
--DECLARE @ipd as varchar(200)
--SET @ipd = (SELECT [Network_IP] FROM [Database].[dbo].[Networks] WHERE [Network_IP] = @IPd)

declare @ip varchar(200)
declare @address varchar(200)
set @address = 
--@ipd  
'24.55.186.203'
set @ip = parsename(@address,1)
DECLARE @Binary   VARCHAR(200)
SET @Binary = ''

   WHILE @IP <> 0
   BEGIN
      SET @Binary = SUBSTRING('0123456789', (@IP % 2) + 1, 1) + @Binary
      SET @IP = @IP / 2
   END

SET @IP = parsename(@address,2)

   WHILE @IP <> 0
   BEGIN
      SET @Binary = SUBSTRING('0123456789', (@IP % 2) + 1, 1) + @Binary
      SET @IP = @IP / 2
   END

SET @IP = parsename(@address,3)

   WHILE @IP <> 0
   BEGIN
      SET @Binary = SUBSTRING('0123456789', (@IP % 2) + 1, 1) + @Binary
      SET @IP = @IP / 2
   END

SET @IP = parsename(@address,4)
   WHILE @IP <> 0
   BEGIN
      SET @Binary = SUBSTRING('0123456789', (@IP % 2) + 1, 1) + @Binary
      SET @IP = @IP / 2
   END

SELECT right('000000000000000000000000000000' + cast(@Binary as varchar),30)
```

I need table like this, but

1. I fail to setup declaration of select or update for more then one address
2. then I fail to  figure out Update of table network
3. then i fail put subnet of_of_IP address into binary format
4. last thing I fail is update of table network and set binary format in to right column.

```
NETWORKS
Network_IP           Network_IP_in_binary           subnet_of_IP         subnet_of_IP_in_binary
24.55.186.203     000110001101111011101111001011        23           000110001101111011101111001011
24.55.185.203     000110001101111011101111001011        45           000110001101111011101111001011
24.55.184.203     000110001101111011101111001011        74           000110001101111011101111001011
24.55.181.203     000110001101111011101111001011        45           000110001101111011101111001011
24.55.183.203     000110001101111011101111001011        78           000110001101111011101111001011
     ...                    ...                        ...                      ...
```

I read articles on sites:

- [SQL to find IP Address in Subnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43860109/sql-to-find-ip-address-in-subnet#43884622)
- [Datatype for storing ip address in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385552/datatype-for-storing-ip-address-in-sql-server/1385701#1385701)

But I can not figure out updates from them.

Comment: You shouldn't use loops or cursors in *any* database. If you want to update multiple columns use an UPDATE query. As for the code itself it's hard to understand what it does - PARSENAME has nothing to do with IPs. You already linked to *working duplicates*. You could use eg `UPDATE NETWORKS SET Network_IP_in_binary=fnBinaryIPv4(Netwokr_IP)` to update all rows at once

Answer (score 0):

Though I agree with Panagiotis's comment, and with the accepted answer in the question you've linked to (that is, store the IP as binary(4) and not as text), You might not be in a position to decide these things (I see a lot of questions about how to work with databases that can't be changed even though an alternate design would solve all the problems) - 
So, to convert an IPv4 address to a string representation of a binary value, you can use a series of bit operations to create that string, for each of the 4 parts of the IP address:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TinyIntToBinaryString(@value tinyint)
RETURNS CHAR(8)
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN CAST(SIGN(@value & 128) as char(1)) +
           CAST(SIGN(@value & 64) as char(1)) +
           CAST(SIGN(@value & 32) as char(1)) + 
           CAST(SIGN(@value & 16) as char(1)) +
           CAST(SIGN(@value & 8) as char(1)) +
           CAST(SIGN(@value & 4) as char(1)) +
           CAST(SIGN(@value & 2) as char(1)) +
           CAST(SIGN(@value & 1)  as char(1)) 
END
```

This will return a string representation of the binary value of any number between 0 to 255 - so `3` will return `00000011`, and `174` will return `10101110`.

Now that you have that, you can use it to convert the entire IP address to it's binary string representation:

```
DECLARE @IP varchar(15) = '24.55.186.203'

SELECT dbo.TinyIntToBinaryString(PARSENAME(@IP, 4)) +
       dbo.TinyIntToBinaryString(PARSENAME(@IP, 3)) +
       dbo.TinyIntToBinaryString(PARSENAME(@IP, 2)) +
       dbo.TinyIntToBinaryString(PARSENAME(@IP, 1))
```

Will result with `00011000001101111011101011001011`

Of course, you can create a function that will convert the entire IP string representation for you - I'll leave that up to you to write.