# IPV6 to integer conversion in TSQL

Tags: t-sql

I need to convert a given IPV6 address to integer. I do that by converting each part of the IP to integer and add those. But Azure Synapse analytics (or SQL Server) BIGINT does not have the capacity to hold the result. As part of the conversion I use power and multiplication that is failing. For example the below multiplication/computation is throwing error

set @Ip = power(65535,7) * 65536

I get the error: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint

Is there any way to achieve the above numerical computation in native SQL query?

Any help or pointers/references to convert IPV6 to integer is much appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: I believe the closest SQL Server has is NUMERIC(38,0) which falls just short. Under the covers, it looks like SQL Server uses a 128 signed integer (16 bytes) plus one byte to manage scale. For IPv6 you will need a 128 unsigned value. You may need to resort to BINARY(16) and work with two bytes at a time as 16 bit unsigned components.

Comment: There is some potentially useful discussion in "*[Datatype for storing ip address in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385552/datatype-for-storing-ip-address-in-sql-server)*". Scroll down for IPv6 content, including some conversion functions that might already implement some of what you are trying to accomplish.